# Android - how to extract/backup your phone contact list and browser bookmarks (stock browser, not chrome)

Tags: android, android-browser, android-backup-service

*Android - how to extract/backup your phone contact list and browser favorites (stock browser, not chrome)*  - a modern **Samsung** smartphone.

Hi, I am grateful for any replies (pls note that we always talk about a non-rooted device, and I have no desire to root it, & I have no desire to use the inherent google-backup methods):

1. How can I extract my entire **contacts** list in a way to be able to import it again to another similar Samsung phone? Any way to do it without using an App for it as workaround? If there is no way around an app, which app(s) would you suggest are considered to be very "safe" and 100% non-malicious?
2. The same question - this time for **calendar** items extraction?
3. Finallly the same question for my Android **Stock Browser** bookmarks (not chrome)? Both, the bookmarks which are available in the "Normal" browser mode, and the bookmarks which are separately stored in the "private" browser mode.

If you know also of a way to doing one of those 3 things but without the ability to import again to another phone, this is also very helpful. My prime interest is in backing up, and if I can import again to another Phone, even better.

Thanks for any technical explanations!

Comment: You should post your question on superuser.com

Comment: @Alexrgs, Can you just explain for the future, how I can differentiate which question is better suited for overflow vs super?  I thought superuser is only for computer related topics and not smartphones, thx

Comment: Sure I can @johnsmiththelird. it's quite simple if it's not a development or development related question it should go somewhere else,otherwise people will just ignore it. In your case it's a advanced user question, so super user is a good fit. You can check all stackexchange sites on https://stackexchange.com/sites each one  with their on related theme. I wish you find your answer.  All the best.